# An error saying "You cannot define a correlation name 'payment' more than once" while taking export

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, export

I am trying to take an export of the orders in the magento backend but I am getting this error. Can anyone let me know How can I resolve this?

```
a:5:{i:0;s:61:"You cannot define a correlation name 'payment' more than once";i:1;s:2483:"#0 /home/uatemrco/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'payment.parent_...', Array, NULL)
#1 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Select.php(373): Varien_Db_Select->_join('left join', Array, 'payment.parent_...', Array, NULL)
#2 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Model/Observer.php(33): Zend_Db_Select->joinLeft(Array, 'payment.parent_...', Array)
#3 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer->salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#4 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer), 'salesOrderGridC...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#5 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_gri...', Array)
#6 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(590): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_gri...', Array)
#7 /home/uatemrco/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(565): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->_beforeLoad()
#8 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(951): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#9 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(1011): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_exportIterateCollection('_exportCsvItem', Array)
#10 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(703): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->getCsvFile()
#11 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->exportCsvAction()
#12 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('exportCsv')
#13 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/uatemrco/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/uatemrco/public_html/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}";s:3:"url";s:118:"/index.php/aksmsrrc/sales_order/exportCsv/key/9252bd3f9da8a80c055a8964c0c0be8c/internal_order_ids/4686,4685,4684,4683/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I use an extension to manipulate and add columns to the export file that I take the code of the observer in the extension is as follows.

```
class Atwix_ExtendedGrid_Model_Observer
{
    /**
     * Joins extra tables for adding custom columns to Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
     * @param Varien_Object $observer
     * @return Atwix_Exgrid_Model_Observer
     */
    public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
    {
        $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        $select = $collection->getSelect();
            $select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('payment_method' => 'method'));
            $select->joinLeft(array('email' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_address')), 'email.parent_id=main_table.entity_id AND email.address_type="shipping"', array('customer_email' => 'email','customer_phone' => 'telephone','shipping_street' => 'street','shipping_city' => 'city','shipping_postcode' => 'postcode','shipping_region' => 'region','shipping_country' => 'country_id'));
            $select->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')));
            $select->group('main_table.entity_id');
    }
    /**
     * callback function used to filter collection
     * @param $collection
     * @param $column
     * @return $this
     */
    public function filterSkus($collection, $column)
    {
        if (!$value = $column->getFilter()->getValue()) {
            return $this;
        }

        $collection->getSelect()->having(
            "group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ', ') like ?", "%$value%");

        return $this;
    }
}
```

and i diplay the colums using another file called grid.php with the code.

**

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Invoice Number', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice #'),
            'index' => 'custom_column',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        ));
        /*if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }*/
        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));
         $this->addColumn('Payment Method', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Payment Method'),
            'index' => 'payment_method',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Customer Email', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Email'),
            'index' => 'customer_email',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('Customer Phone', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Phone'),
            'index' => 'customer_phone',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        )); 

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency::NO_SYMBOL',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
            'index' => 'grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency::NO_SYMBOL',
            'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('street', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Street'),
            'index' => 'shipping_street',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('city', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping City'),
            'index' => 'shipping_city',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('postcode', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Postcode'),
            'index' => 'shipping_postcode',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('region', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Region'),
            'index' => 'shipping_region',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('country', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Country Id'),
            'index' => 'shipping_country',
            'column_css_class'=>'no-display',
            'header_css_class'=>'no-display',
        ));
        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
```

**

Comment: Do you use any extensions in your backend? Anything that alters the order collection or the export functionality?

Comment: @Arjen Miedema Yes, I use an extension called atwix that would allow me to manipulate and add up new columns to the export. I have added 3 extra columns using it. I will edit the question and add the code of the that too.

Comment: @ArjenMiedema I have edited the question with the code related to the extension i am using.

Comment: Did you try to disable this extension to see what happens then?

Answer (score 4):

The error is related to `join` query you are using. If you debug the error it will take you to the `Zend_Db_Select::_join()` function.
The arguments passed to this function are `($type, $name, $cond, $cols, $schema = null)`
This function checks for correlation names already added to the query. If any duplicate is found, it will throw exception.

```
throw new Zend_Db_Select_Exception("You cannot define a correlation name '$correlationName' more than once");
```

Try with below code in your `salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore` function.

```
public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
    $select = $collection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(array('custom_payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'custom_payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('payment_method' => 'method'));
        $select->joinLeft(array('email' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_address')), 'email.parent_id=main_table.entity_id AND email.address_type="shipping"', array('customer_email' => 'email','customer_phone' => 'telephone','shipping_street' => 'street','shipping_city' => 'city','shipping_postcode' => 'postcode','shipping_region' => 'region','shipping_country' => 'country_id'));
        $select->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')));
        $select->group('main_table.entity_id');
}
```